# How to "speed up" a series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k=\ell$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

### Introduction

I was numerically calculating some limits of functions and series and I noticed a disparity:

I have a function $f(x)$ such that: $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\ell$$ and I want to numerically calculate an approximation of $\ell$.

Let (for example) $N=1000$ $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to N}f(x)=\ell_1$$

From a numerical point of view, if I wanted to reach a more accurate approximation of $\ell$ I just need to replace $x$ with a "faster" function (for example $e^x$).

I define $g(x):=f(e^x)$ so I have:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to N}g(x)=\ell_2$$

Where: $$|\ell_2-\ell|\leq |\ell_1-\ell|$$

This is a very trivial example, but clearly $g(x)$ reaches the $\ell$ limit faster than $f(x)$

### Question

Given a generic convergent series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k=\ell$$

which converges to its limit "slowly".

Is it possible to generate a $b_k$ series that converges to the same limit but faster?

**Mathematically speaking**

If
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k=\ell$$
and I calculate (for example)
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_k=\ell_1$$
where $N=1000$, it is possible to generate a sequence $b_k$ such that:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}b_k=\ell_2$$

Where $|\ell_2-\ell|\leq |\ell_1-\ell|$?

---

#### Edit:

An example of a series that converges very slowly is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\frac{1}{2}+n}\cdot\ln\left(n+1\right)\approx -0.23117606098678711$$

I calculated that value with Wolfram, but normally I use a calculator which obviously doesn't reach infinity, but I give it the extremes of the calculation. So my input is something like:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\frac{1}{2}+n}\cdot\ln\left(n+1\right)$$

It reaches:
$1$ decimal correct digits for $N=69^{*}$
$2$ decimal correct digits for $N=3\,471^{**}$
$3$ decimal correct digits for $N=29\,199$
$4$ decimal correct digits for $N=260\, 456$
$5$ decimal correct digits for $N=1\,830\,414$
$6$ decimal correct digits for $N=154\,593\,396$

*The first time it appears is with $N=22$, but being a series of alternating signs with $N=24$ we no longer have the correct figure, so I sign the numbers from which the digits continues to be constantly correct
**The first time it appears is with $N=329$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration

Comment: @QiaochuYuan's link is a good starting point. But if you have a specific sequence or function in mind please add it to your question, because there's no general way to do it. The basic reason is sequences can converge arbitrarily slowly, but the utility of a specific acceleration technique hinges on the original sequence converging fast enough.

Comment: @J.G. Ok, I'll edit the question and tag you as soon as I'm done

Comment: Cool. In the mean time, I found [the theorem](https://www.cristal.univ-lille.fr/~jdelahay/dnalor/DelahayeBGBSetofLogarithmic1982.pdf) I was trying to remember that makes what I was saying more precise.

Comment: @J.G. I edited it

Comment: Right. Get the first 1000 or so partial sums, then try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation) two or three times. The log factor might make it behave a bit worse, but it should still be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recent editing.

Comment: @Sebastiano Di nulla, per caso sai per quale motivo non si ricevono più punti a seguito delle modifiche dei post? All'inizio davano 2 voti per ogni domanda editata, adesso più nulla, sono cambiate le regole o è perché ho raggiunto un punteggio "così alto" che ora non ricevo più punti dalle modifiche dei post? Il mio intento sarebbe arrivarre al rango massimo, ma diventa difficile se ci si basa solo sugli upvoti dei post (i post vecchi vedo che hanno ricevuto più voti forse perché prima il sito era più usato non so... ora come si fa se uno volesse raggiungere un punteggio alto?)

Comment: @MathAttack Kindly, meanwhile, I ask you a kindness to convert your comment into English. I wouldn't want you to be reprimanded by the moderators later. The two points for each edited question are not infinite but rather if you get to a certain score, let's say 2500 points, .......

Comment: @MathAttack after that for each edited question you will not receive any points. So you will acquire the points by editing tags, or by accepting an answer to your question, or by other methods. I can vote for you ahahhahaha. I'm sorry but some of your nice answers I voted for :-). My best regards.

Answer (score 2):

*Probably too advanced but made for your curiosity.*

One thing that you could do is to write $(a=\frac 12)$
$$\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n+1-a}\,\log\left(n+1\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k}\, (-1)^n \,\frac{\log (n+1)}{(n+1)^{k+1} }$$ and use
$$S_k=2^{-k}\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \, \frac{\log (n+1)}{(n+1)^{k+1} }$$ $$S_k=-2^{-2k} \left(\left(2^k-1\right) \zeta '(k+1)+\log (2)\, \zeta
   (k+1)\right)$$ Now, computing the partial sums
$$\Sigma_p=-\frac{1}{2} (2 \gamma -\log (2)) \log (2)+\sum_{k=1}^p S_k$$

$$\Sigma_{28}=-0.23117606098678711$$

The fast convergence is due to the fact that
$$0.250 <\frac{S_{k+1}}{S_k} <0.295 \qquad \forall k >0$$
$$0.250 <\frac{S_{k+1}}{S_k} <0.251 \qquad \forall k >10$$

**Edit**

For the infinite summation, write it as

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\,\frac{\log\left(n+1\right)}{n+\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{p}\left(-1\right)^{n}\,\frac{\log\left(n+1\right)}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\sum_{n=p+1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\,\frac{\log\left(n+1\right)}{n+\frac{1}{2}}$$ and you want to know $p$ such that
$$\frac{\log (p+2)}{p+\frac{3}{2}} \leq 10^{-m}$$ The solution is given in terms of Lambert function
$$p=-10^m\,\, W_{-1}\left(-e^{-\frac{10^{-m}}{2}}
   \,10^{-m}\right)-2$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m &\lceil p_m\rceil\\
 1 & 35 \\
 2 & 646 \\
 3 & 9117 \\
 4 & 116670 \\
 5 & 1416359 \\
 6 & 16626508 \\
 7 & 190660023 \\
 8 & 2148818393 \\
 9 & 23897019584 \\
 10 & 262952388191 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This explains your numbers.

Comment: Shouldn’t there be a sum over $k$ on the RHS of the first equation?

Comment: @sasquires. Thanks for pointing it ! Cheers :-)